# How to work with a micro-manage client

Tags: contracts, freelance-websites, difficult-client, communication, client-support

I have work with a client for nearly a week and I am really stress to cooperate with him. I apply for a blog writer for this job through a freelance platform. I have a feeling of being controlled, he tracks me in every step even bothers me at the midnight and I hate that feeling. Moreover, I feel compelled to complete an assignment to the client’s exact specifications rather than exploring other solutions that might provide superior results. So what should I do, how can I deal with him, please give me an advice!!!

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes the money is not worth it.

I offer discounted prices for well-behaved clients, and I overcharged the ones that are, well, no good people.

Here's how you've got to look at it, the client is paying for you, which means that every resource he asks for that you need to use, has to be paid for.

Is he paying for your blogging skills only? I don't think so. He also has to pay for your patience, for 24/7 support, for being rude, for being demanding.

You don't need to fire the client, you just need to put a price on the job.

Support is handled by email.

Does he want to instant message you on whatsapp/telegram/ig/sms/whatever? **it costs extra**

Does he want you to be available 24/7? **it costs extra!**

It's called premium support. Charge for it.
If the client pays, I bet you will be happy to answer him late at night!

Now just take that logic and apply to everything that annoys you in a client.

Extra reviews? Extra money

Extra meetings? Extra money

You are not an employee, if something it's not on paper, on a contract or written email agreement, then you don't have to do it. Learn to say no and learn to negotiate those terms.

Answer (score 7):

Generally, you cannot change clients; you can merely select the ones you want to work for and those you don't. The only factor where you are in full control is how you handle a client.

For some freelancers, good money can make micro-management bearable. Only you know if that applies to you. I'm assuming the client pays you on time, so that is not an additional problem.

Regarding the 'tracking every step': Can you not go offline or be otherwise unresponsive for hours or days at a time? At times micro-management happens because it is allowed or tolerated. This seems to be the case here.

You could attempt to re-take control by setting milestones, like 'In four days, I will have the first draft of XYZ' - and then be unresponsive. If the client complains, simply state that you have commitments from other clients that must also be undertaken - even if this is not true.

Be the client's service provider, but not their slave.

Comment: "money can make a micro-management bearable" That is a nice statement. for add more information to this answer I think is a good idea talk about the task and the expectations when you contact the client you have to know all the details so in that way you will have a clause that says this is out of my contract, you asked me to only do this or "the time is fixed"

Comment: If you want to know more about what to do maybe this post in [workplace.stackexchange](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/21665/how-to-work-with-a-micro-manager) They have 44 questions related to [micro-management](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/micro-management) but in freelance is different so try to select and apply this answers.

Answer (score 2):

Every time the client contacts you out of working hours, bill them for the time at an increased rate (work out different rates for “slightly out of working hours” and “unreasonable hours” - don’t use those terms, just specify the hours).

There might be times when the client doesn’t want to agree to a tiered support plan and will contact you anyway.

You should really let the client know that each call is chargeable before helping them.

Of course, this all depends on the wording of your contract. If you’ve opened yourself up to 24/7 unlimited support, there’s nothing you can do except extract yourself from the contract (and client).